# VB.Net DataGridView Bindingsource.Filter , show blank row if nothing found

Tags: vb.net, filter, datagridview, bindingsource

Is there way to show an empty row in DataGridView when nothing found?

```
 'EQTYPBS.Filter = "eID ='" & SelectedEQP & "'"
```

for example in the above code when the string SelectedEQP exists in the column eID then it shows the result when not found it shows the error but i want there a single empty row. Any idea how to achieve that? thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you mean, but if your grid allows user to add rows then there will be an empty row at the bottom. I think you just need to handle/fix your exception.

Comment: Create a  copy datasource that matches the columns of your existing datasource that just contains a single blank row.  If the filter returns no results, just set the DataGridView datasource to your blank one.  Remember to swap it back before you next apply a filter.

Comment: Is there a way to filter a blank row using bindingsource.filter  with above code?